# whatever i do i can't access the external URL for the site or UI

Tags: browser-sync

All external URLs work on my machine but not on other devices on the same network. In over a year it never really has but now it would be really handy for my workflow.

I have used dev-ip and set the correct IP. I use mamp pro and tried various ports and its defaults (80, 8888). The Ips are correct too.

Using those ports instead of the below yields no results. I think i should of been able to at least access the UI External from another device on the same network but cannot.

Any help appreciated or if any more info would help please let me know!

I have 30+ sites in mamp pro so always use the proxy setting incase i'm working on more than one at a time. Being able to use http://10.50.2.64:3000 on same network machines would be amazing!

```
[BS] Proxying: http://ggdev.jynk.net.local
[BS] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.50.2.64:3000
 -----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.50.2.64:3001
```

browserSync (latest version) & gulp settings -

```
browserSync.init({
files: ['{lib,templates,templates-misc}/**/*.php', '*.php'],
notify: false,
watchTask: true,
open:false,
proxy: config.devUrl,
host: "10.50.2.64",
snippetOptions: {
  whitelist: ['/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'],
  blacklist: ['/wp-admin/**']
}
});
```

Any help appreciated. D.

Comment: Shutdown your firewall and test again, if works you need update and config your firewall rules.

Comment: For me was related to VirtualBox installation. For some reason browser-sync is getting the IP of the virtual machine. I disable the "Virtualbox Host-Only Network" in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections, then works on every device like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your command line to open port **3000/tcp** in your machine (Ubuntu):

```
sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp
```